# Plot the values of each column as histogram

Tags: r, plot, statistics, histogram

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

`Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday Monday.1 Tuesday.1
  5.3     2.2      1          7      8.3     5       6.4     7         2`

And I want the desired plot like shown in the Image:

Any help would be grateful

Dput:

```
structure(list(Wednesday = 7.4375, Thursday = 7.94791666666667, 
    Friday = 7.14583333333333, Saturday = 4.325, Sunday = 4.41304347826087, 
    Monday = 7.95125, Tuesday = 8.09375, Wednesday.1 = 7.85416666666667, 
    Thursday.1 = 8.58333333333333, Friday.1 = 6.02173913043478, 
    Saturday.1 = 2.80952380952381, Sunday.1 = 2.66666666666667), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: (nil)>)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you only have one record? Can you try to provide a part of your data by using `dput` and pasting the results in the question?

Comment: yes it it only one record. Its the mean values of each day of the week like shown above

Comment: @AndersEllernBilgrau edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot(1:NCOL(df1), df1[1,], type = "h", lwd = 4, lend = "butt", xaxt = "n")
lines(spline(1:NCOL(df1), df1[1,]))
axis(1, at = 1:NCOL(df1), labels = names(df1), las = 2)
```